# 502 Bad Gateway Error, when attempting to upload files to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am having a very difficult time figuring out why i cannot upload files to my Wordpress Uploads folder. I have tried to scour the web to no avail of anything that has fixed this. I keep getting a 502 Bad gateway error once the submit button is pressed. The commented area is for eventually storing the files into a database. I need to get any file actually moved at this point. I have created a quick and dirty little php script that uses my methods. If anything stands out please let me know.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: testFileUpload */

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
* User: ccombs
* Date: 7/27/2017
* Time: 1:31 PM
*/

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$file = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
$fileoverride = array('test_form' => false);

/*//file upload for resume and error checking
if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] != 0) {
       $externalDB->insert('emp_resume', array(
               'resume_name' => $file,
               'resume_type' => $file_type,
               'resume_size' => $file_size,
               'resume_contents' => $file_content,
               'applicantid' => $lastid
       ));
   }
*/
if(isset($_POST[('submitted')])) {

wp_handle_upload($file, $fileoverride);
}

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($file); ?>
<? get_template_part( 'content-583', get_post_format() );?>
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post"  id="app" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="font-weight: bold">
        Attach your resume:
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="btn">

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<div><?php get_footer(); ?></div>
```

Comment: Try looking up the errors in your error.log file on your server

Answer (score 0):

I contacted GoDaddy which was my hosting provider. They informed me that they have a "difficult time" uploading .docx files to wordpress sites. So I tested and a .doc, .pdf, .jpeg, .png and others uploaded just fine. Every time i went to upload a .docx file the server would return a Bad Gateway 502.